# Native Error: [25037] - There is not enough disk space left for the Database (Windows Compact)

Tags: java, c#, windows, sql-server-ce, windows-ce

Getting disk space unavailable message but have enough memory in the `Nand Flash` directory in the Windows Compact device.

As the problem shows at the client side, it is difficult to figure out through debugging. Software is running 24/7. Software does auto reboot if something goes wrong. Seems during the boot up process, software sees out of memory and it creates problem for other process. Some error shows like this on the log file and repeatedly writing the same error information:

> SQL Server CE Error 1 of 1 HR: -2147467259 Native Error: [25037] - There is
>   not enough disk space left for the database
>   Message:
>   ---------- | modDatabase.DoExecuteNonQuery
>   2015.11.02 *** 00:15:02.39796964 --->Exception Error - Location :modDatabase.DoExecuteNonQuery | Description : Caught SQL Server CE Exception
>
>   executing SQL : | Error Message :UPDATE tblTxtn SET exported = 2 WHERE
>   isactive = 0 and (   Exported = 1 OR Exported = 4)
>   2015.11.02 *** 00:15:02.39797008 --->Exception Error - Location :modDatabase.DoExecuteNonQuery | Description : Caught SQL Server CE Exception
>   | Error Message :SQL Server CE Error|
>
> 2015.10.28 *** 10:05:27.78586 --->Exception Error Trying to Append or Create File :\Nand Flash\Logs\C0023_S002_2015_10_28-Log.txt | Error
>   :IOException | Saving message :     Event Log: | Problem backing up SG
>   folder| frmStartup
>   2015.10.28 *** 10:05:27.78702 --->Exception Error - Location :CDatabase.GetConnection | Description : Invalid Operation Exception -
>   Opening Connection for : \NAND Flash\SG5\SentryGold5.sdf | Error
>   Message :SqlCeConnection
>
> 2015.02.13 *** 02:57:23.43180937 --->Exception Error - Location :modcontroller:Main() | Description : Unhandled Exception Error
>   Catched pre-final - On Main() | Error Message
>   :System.ArgumentException: URI formats are not supported.    at
>   System.IO.Path.NormalizePathFast(String path, Boolean fullCheck)    at
>   System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(String path, DirectorySecurity
>   directorySecurity)    at SG5.modController.GetCurrDir()    at
>   SG5.modController.Main()

The code is written using **.NET 3.5 API** in visual studio.

- OS: Windows CE 6.0
- RAM: 128MB (Storage: 32MB, Program memory: 100MB)
- Nand Flash: 256MB

My questions are:

- Is the problem of database or Nand Flash or RAM memory becomes full as there is no reason found to be memory becomes full
- Or as multiple threads are running so, those are messed up for any reason
- Is it a problem of the OS, I mean some registry values changes or can not changes
- Or the code itself has issue
- or the .net framework can not handle it
- or memory does not release properly; As it is running fine at the development environment; so, I am not sure about that.

Thank you.

Comment: Most  likely a hardware or flash driver issue, check the vendor for updated drivers. Looking at the log, it does not seem to be releated to SQLCE, but a general IO issue

Comment: Thank you for your comment. CE device is communicating with some other hardwares and getting status of those hardwares.

Comment: So, you mean only communication issue not OS or software right? CE device is communicating with some other hardware and getting status of those  hardware. Client sent that unit for test and it is working fine at the development place. I saw that same version of software is running at the client end. Some of the customer uses the same version of OS software. I want to print the memory status (nand flash, os, software) in order to determine which causes the error and the status at that time. Can you recommend some ways to recreate the issue at the development place?  Thank you.